# Scipy standard deviation

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to calculate standard deviation for some distribution and keep getting two different results from two paths. It doesn't make much sense to me - could someone explain why is this happening?

```
scipy.stats.binom(189, 100/189).std()
6.8622115305451707

scipy.stats.tstd([1]*100 + [0]*89)
0.50047821327986164
```

Why aren't those two numbers equal?

Answer (score 7):

The basic reason is that you're taking the standard deviation of two quite different things there.  I think you're misunderstanding what `scipy.stats.binom` does.  From [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom.html#scipy.stats.binom):

> The probability mass function for binom is:
>
> `binom.pmf(k) = choose(n,k) * p**k * (1-p)**(n-k)`
>
> for k in {0,1,...,n}.
>
> binom takes n and p as shape parameters.

When you do `binom(189, 100/189)`, you are creating a distribution that could take on any value from 0 to 189.  This distribution unsurprisingly has a much larger variance than the other sample data you're using, which is restricted to values of either zero or one.

It looks like what you want would be `scipy.stats.binom(1, 100/189).std()`.  However, you still can't expect the exact same value as what you're getting with your sample data, because the `binom.std` is computing the standard deviation of the overall distribution, whereas the other version (`scipy.stats.tstd([1]*100 + [0]*89)`) is computing the standard deviation only of a sample.  If you increase the size of your sample (e.g., do `scipy.stats.tstd([1]*1000 + [0]*890)`), the sample standard deviation will approach the value you're getting from `binom.std`.

You can also get the population (not sample) std by using `scipy.std` or `numpy.std` instead of `scipy.stats.tstd`. `scipy.stats.tstd` doesn't have a `ddof` option to let you choose the degrees of freedom, and always computes a sample `std`.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there any way to get the same value as tstd without creating the values themselves? From what I read, the result should be related to `scipy.stats.binom(1, 100/189).std()` in that case...

Comment: @viraptor: See my edited answer.  You can't get the exact same value because in one case you're computing the "real" distribution std, and in the other you're only getting the std of a small sample.  But if you increase the sample size the values will get closer and closer.

Comment: @BrenBarn: I'm not sure that your "real" vs. "sample" argument is right.  ISTM it's really just a DOF issue. `scipy.stats.binom(1, 100./189).std() == 0.49915244084955573 == numpy.std([1]*100 + [0]*89)`.  OTOH, `scipy.stats.tstd([1]*100 + [0]*89) == 0.50047821327986164 == numpy.std([1]*100 + [0]*89, ddof=1)`.

Comment: @DSM: Yeah, that's what I meant, but you're right, I didn't state it clearly.  I mean that `tstd` is computing the sample (not population) std.  I edited my answer to include some info on that and mention `scipy.std` as an alternative.

Comment: I think that reads much better.  Otherwise it sounded like we wouldn't expect the results to be identically equal except in the large-sample limit.  Unfortunately I'd already given you +1 so I can't do it again. :^)

Comment: beautifully done with ```numpy.array([a,b,c,d,e]).std()```, thanks chief!

Comment: this is the same result as ```statistics.pstdev([a,b,c,d,e])```